Azure VMSS machine names on scale set (self hosted)
We're trying to scale out a self hosted VM (windows datacenter). Problem is the machine name does not change on each instance of the scale set that is spun up. If, for example our master image has a windows OS name of 'BuildMaster', then all the instances in the VMSS also have the machine name 'BuildMaster'. Tried using the --computername-prefix, tried domain joining, tried adding the various dns options.
Added the scalable agent pool in DevOps.
What happens is that multiple VMs are spun up but only one agent is produced and only one pipeline job can be run at a time.
Any pointers?

Using VMSS agent pools for Azure DevOps Services is only supported for Azure Public (global service) cloud. Currently, VMSS agent pools does not support any other national cloud offerings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops
...ah nuts. Public only!
